# SenseHat connection with raspberrypi3

Tags: raspberry-pi3

Hi I am getting the following error while connecting `SenseHat` module to `raspberry` pi.

File "`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 39, in __init__`

raise `OSError('Cannot detect %s device' % self.SENSE_HAT_FB_NAME)`

```
OSError: Cannot detect RPi-Sense FB device
```

Kindly help out.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enabled I2C via `raspi-config`. 
Update Raspberry Pi with command `rpi-update`.
If there is still same error, try to edit `/boot/config.txt` and add this line to the end of file: `dtoverlay=rpi-sense`. Save, reboot and try.